# Is this a correct way to enable htaccess in Apache 2.4.7

Tags: apache2, configuration, .htaccess

In almost every solution of "How to activate htaccess", they say that the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file needs to be edited. But there isn't such file in Apache 2.4.7

I read somewhere that the new default file is 000-default.conf.  So I edited that one and tried to add the line:

```
AllowOverride All
```

But Apache2 did not restart correctly and gave an error. From an apache2 documentation, I found that AllowOverride is only allowed under the `<Directory>` section. Then I tried adding this:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And this seems to work. But I am not sure if I should have put /var/www there. Is it a correct way of doing it or will my computer blow up somehow?

Comment: see this. It might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062142/why-codeigniter-show-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server/41862237#41862237

Comment: My "global config" was in `etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, where I found my `<Directory>` declarations.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

### tl;dr

Yes it's the correct way.
But to be more *semantic*: Yes, it's the correct way to allow `.htaccess` to override all directives in the `/var/www` directory.

---

As you found out, [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#AllowOverride) is allowed only under the `Directory` section.

Using your example:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

This is telling apache, that all configurations can be overridden in the `/var/www` and all its sub-directories (recursively).

---

For a better example, consider you have the following configuration in your virtual host:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/uploads">
    AllowOverride Limit
</Directory>
```

And the following directory structure:

```
var/
    www/
        .htaccess
        uploads/
            .htaccess
            a/
                .htaccess
            b/
                .htaccess
        code/
            .htaccess
            c/
                .htaccess
            d/
                .htaccess
```

What I did here, is create an `.htaccess` in every sub-directory of the `/var/www` directory.
<sup>*It usually shouldn't be like so, but this is just for the sake of the example*</sup>

Comparing the directory structure with the configuration, it means that all `.htaccess` files inside in the `/var/www` folder and its sub-directories, excluding the `/var/www/uploads` directory and its sub-directories, can override all kinds of directives.

But `/var/www/uploads` and its sub-directories can only use the `.htaccess` file to override the `Allow`, `Deny` and `Order` directives.

<sup>Note: As of apache 2.4 (Which is available by default in 13.10+) the `Allow`, `Deny` and `Order` directives were replaced by a single directive named `Require`.</sup>

Answer (score 46):

First enable rewrite using this command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then go into the `sites-available` folder:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Edit the file named `default` and change `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All`. There are two lines where this change has to be made.

This will make `.htaccess` work in your server VPS.

This worked on an Ubuntu 12.04.5 VPS.

Comment: there is no file named default - but there is a file named 000-default.conf

Comment: +1 for reminding to enable the rewrite, i was missing this and couldn't figure out why its not working after doing all the stuff.

Comment: This comment refers to the configuration of Apache 2.2, not 2.4. In 2.4, the `default` file is called  `000-default.conf`, and it doesn't contain the `AllowOverride None` line.

Comment: the file is `000-default.conf` and it's not possible to add `AllowOverride None` here, if you reload apache give error

Comment: If all you need is to allow mod_rewrite directives to be overridden in `.htaccess`, its better to use [`AllowOverride FileInfo`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/overrides.html#override-fileinfo). Although FileInfo already includes a large set of directives, you would still be restricting lots of directives from being overridden.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it worked like this:
I had to add the following lines:

```
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
```

So it looks like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Although this may have fixed your problem, it is not related to the question the OP has. The order and allow directives are directives in apache2.2 and earlier. They are used to allow/deny access to users on certain directories. They don't have any impact on whether the directives in a .htaccess file would be parsed or not.

Answer (score 3):

Here a snippet how to enable htaccess in Apache 2.4 without change the default configuration:

```
cat <<EOF> /etc/apache2/conf-available/allow-override.conf
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
EOF

a2enconf allow-override
service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 2):

A common problem i ran into in these tutorials is that there's no default.conf file in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

I was able to find the place to change it,but it was the apache2.conf file here

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Not really sure if this is a good idea, but it did work for me, and in the environment I'm in it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

For those running apache 2.4 and not finding "default" look in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and edit

```
Directory 
 
AllowOverride All

Directory
```

---

```
Directory /var/www/>

AllowOverride All 
  
Directory
```