# RewriteRule not working with PHP-FPM Ubuntu 18

Tags: apache2, php

I have just installed successfully PHP-FPM in Ubuntu 18.04.5 and PHP Version 7.4.11.

However there is one problem with the Rewrite in a .htacess file. This works fine on another server and is known to work everywhere else.

```
# Rules to set ApplicationContext based on hostname

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.de$
RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development]
```

It never detects the variable TYPO3_CONTEXT set to Development on the url [www.example.de](http://www.example.de) .

All the installation has been done following https://www.digitalocean.com/ .

What is wrong here?

Comment: In the virtual hosts' configuration, have you allowed .htaccess to set directives? What's the value of `AllowOverride`?

Comment: Related: [Is this a correct way to enable htaccess in Apache 2.4.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429869/is-this-a-correct-way-to-enable-htaccess-in-apache-2-4-7)

Comment: ``Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted``